# SVG animation : tspan translation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am trying to animate every letter of svg a text element (make then jump) on hover. For this I put every letter in a `<tspan>` and add an animation on it, anyway transform doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
svg text tspan {
 fill: #666;
 animation:jump 5s linear;
}

@keyframes jump {
 100% {
  fill: red;
  transform: translateY(40px);
 }
}
</style>

<body>

 <svg overflow="visible">
  <text font-size="20px" x="0" y="21"><tspan>t</tspan><tspan>e</tspan><tspan >s</tspan><tspan >t</tspan></text>
     <text font-size="20px" x="0" y="42"><tspan>2 </tspan><tspan>l</tspan><tspan>i</tspan><tspan>g</tspan><tspan>n</tspan><tspan>e</tspan></text>
 </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use CSS animation here, you need SMIL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This animates each letter via SMIL. It's a bit repetitive as SMIL animations only apply to a single target.

We also have to avoid having whitespace in the wrong places or the text element will assume we actually want to display it rather than having it for neatness.

```html
<svg>
  <text y="50 50 50 50">
    <tspan>T<animate
         attributeName="dy" from="0" to="-40"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /><set
         attributeName="fill" to="red"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /></tspan><tspan>e<animate
         attributeName="dy" from="0" to="-40"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /><set
         attributeName="fill" to="red"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /></tspan><tspan>s<animate
         attributeName="dy" from="0" to="-40"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /><set
         attributeName="fill" to="red"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /></tspan><tspan>t<animate
         attributeName="dy" from="0" to="-40"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /><set
         attributeName="fill" to="red"
         dur="5s" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" /></tspan></text>
</svg>
```